# Showing too much recursion in over query limit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Showing too much recursion  when google map api return status over query limit. How we    solve it.

```
function calcRoute(origi,desti,planid,segno,routeType,imageUrl) {
 var request = {
 origin: origi,
 destination: desti,
 travelMode: routeType
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
 //alert("status is "+status);
 if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
 computeTotalDistance( response,planid,segno,routeType,origi,desti,imageUrl);
 //alert("origi "+origi+" desti "+desti);
}
 else if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
 // usleep(10000);
 wait = true;
 setTimeout("wait = true", 200000);
 calcRoute(origi,desti,planid,segno,routeType,imageUrl);
 //calcRoute(origi,desti,planid,segno,routeType);
 }

 });
}
 showing too much reursion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `setTimeout()` doesn't help you because `setTimeout()` puts `"wait = true"` in the queue and returns. `"wait = true"` will be executed after 200s but `calcRoute()` is called immediately.

If you want to call calcRoute() after some delay use:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    calcRoute(origi,desti,planid,segno,routeType,imageUrl);
}, 2000);
```